# JAXB - How to use XmlAdapter for unmarshalling a list when wrapper element is root?

Tags: java, jaxb, hashmap, wrapper, unmarshalling

Exists a way to unmarshall a list to a map when the wrapper element of the list is the root itself?

I have following xml structure which I cannot change:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <article id="1">...</article>
     <article id="2">...</article>
    ...
  </root>
```

And I like to have the following Map Structure:

```
Map<Integer,Article> map
```

I tried to use the XmlAdapter but the problem is the unmarshal method of the adapter. Here it likes to have an own wrapper element e.g. "articles" which I don't have. I found only [working examples](http://mjremijan.blogspot.ch/2013/03/jaxb-unmarshalling-to-sorted-map.html) where the list had its own dedicated wrapper element.

I tried with "unmarshall(List articles)" but then it gets never called. And with "unmarshall(Object articles)" it will call th method for every article element

Any hints?

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DataSet {
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAdapter.class)
   @XmlElement(name="article")
   private Map<Integer,Article> map;
}

public class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter< ??? , Map<Integer,Article>  {

    @Override
    public Map<Integer, Article> unmarshal( ???  ) throws Exception {
     Map<Integer, Article> map = new HashMap<Integer, Article>();
     ...
     return map;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers is, it is currently not supported and you need to do it yourself, means after unmarshalling you need to iterate through the list of objects and put them to the map by yourself